# Php convert datetime from twitter feed

Tags: php, datetime

Hey all i have this date for one of my twitter feeds:

```
Tue Apr 16 17:39:59 +0000 2013
```

Problem is that this code below does not seem to format it?

```
$date = new DateTime('Tue Apr 16 17:39:59 +0000 2013');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It just shows up as a blank page.

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine on my machine

Comment: It does work. You error must be elsewhere: http://codepad.viper-7.com/nCHN4h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M j H:i:s O Y', 'Tue Apr 16 17:39:59 +0000 2013');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/krzIRu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = 'Tue Apr 16 17:39:59 +0000 2013';
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to my question, Navnath.

Answer (score 0):

i've tested out your code on a console app with php and works fine. 
I think that maybe you have a problem with the code that display the page in the browser.
Other thing that you can try is to inspect the source of the page and see if is showing there.
BTW, i'm using PHP 5.4.7

Comment: Thanks for contributing to my question, Stephan.